# SQL Server statement with bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, bulk

I am working on a project where I have used the bulk insert statement to import a batch `.csv` file into a table.

The problem I have is that some of the records are duplicates to what is currently in the table I am looking to import data into. Is there a way to run a statement with the bulk insert to check for specific rows that match the file rows based off of certain criteria?

I am sure there is a way to make this work, just nothing I have in mind.

Comment: i'm pretty sure we already have this case somewhere... the other way would be just insert them and delete duplicates

Comment: Is there a query I can use to search and delete duplicates in one batch?

Comment: Group by having count () > 1, to find duplicates

Answer (score 0):

No, the `BULK INSERT` statement is optimized for **raw speed** - it just inserts that data as quickly as possible - but it does **not** allow for inspection or decisions to be made while importing.

The usual approach in such a case is to bulk insert your data into a **staging table**, and then after that's done, copy only those rows that are not duplicates into the actual data table and discard everything else.

But that's a separate step - cannot be done *while* bulk inserting ....

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I am a junior level with sql.  Is there a query I can use to search batch rows of data and either print all the duplicates, or delete duplicates based off of the criteria of a matching column?